# How to recursively call a block and return a value

Tags: ruby, recursion

`knight.moves` is an array of instances of knights at other positions.

If I print out `knight.position` and `target` together, there are times where they're equal, but the method doesn't return anything.

I think it has something to do with how blocks handle returns, but I haven't figured it out.

My code looks like this:

```
def dfs_rec knight, target  
  if knight
    if knight.position == target
      return knight
    end

    moves = knight.moves.size - 1
    moves.times do |num|
      dfs_rec knight.moves[num], target
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: you're not calling `return` explicitly from a block, so the behavior should be the same

Comment: It seems to work for me, I tried calling as `dfs_rec(OpenStruct.new(position: 1), 1)` and it returned the `OpenStruct` instance.

Comment: @kris it works if the first object matches, but not after.

Comment: I see now that the iterator treats the recursive call as though it were any other method. I'd need to collect the knights into some array at global scope to do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Why not refactor to something more like this?

```
class Knight
  def at_position?(target_position)
    position == target_position
  end

  def can_move_to?(target_position)
    moves.include?(target_position)
  end
end

# to find a knight in an array of knights that can move to `position`
knights.select { |knight| knight.can_move_to?(position) || knight.at_position?(position) } #=> [ <Knight>, <Knight> ]
```

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably just do something like this. Thanks!

Comment: @robert Great — if this answered your question go ahead and accept it with the checkmark on the left so other users know you're all set.